# How to extract JDBC Request response?

Tags: jmeter, extractor

My JDBC request response is as below,

```
request_token   create_date
Vve5vyD42ZPr5ssTIduzy1l6cvb/hDPaCMXnF8cFcpaCfdRMvNChB43I+JSgmgvy2owklXPRGvIVolDhb12lU2dIXko6ajlqyKoh3RjhPYo=    2015-02-25 18:56:00.0
```

How to extract only 'request token' from the response?

Answer (score 1):

In your JDBC Sampler add the following values into "Variables" input:

```
token,date
```

See below image for details:

[image: JDBC Variables]

You'll be able to refer "request_token" value as `${token_1}` and "create_date" value as `${date_1}`

See the following material for more information:

- [JDBC Request Sampler Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
- [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter)